# Is rebooked flight considered a delay

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, delays, ec261

If I miss a flight from Warsaw (WAW) to Toronto (YYZ) due to the delay of an inbound connection (Moscow (SVO) to WAW), that was purchased from the same airline on the same ticket, and they can only rebook me on the same flight the next day, would it be considered a delay of 24 hours? (even though the actual delay on the first flight was only 2 hours, and second one technically leaves on time)

If it is considered a delay and the airline needs to provide accommodations, how does the presence or absence of visa for the transit country impact it?

Comment: Can you specify the airline and the involved countries or ideally airports? Depending on the situation, this could be a matter of regulations or just a contractual obligation.

Comment: @jcaron I've updated question. Delayed flight is Moscow SVO to Warsaw WAW and rebooked flight is Warsaw WAW to Toronto YYZ, all tickets are purchased from LOT, so i believe it should be a subject to European regulation.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that you *wouldn't* be due compensation (other than the ever-present "extraordinary circumstances" exception) is because your travel both started and ended outside of the EU.  I'm not sure whether EC 261 regulations apply to connections through the EU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are covered by both the 'Right to care' and 'Compensation' sections of [EU261](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32004R0261:en:HTML), due to the fact the airline you were flying was an EU carrier - and all EU carriers are covered by EU261 regardless of where the flight is to/from.

'Right of care' means that regardless of the reason for the delay they are required to provide you with accommodation, transportation to the accommodation, and relevant meals during your delay.

'Compensation' will depend on the reason for the delay, but in most cases you would be eligible for 600 Euro compensation based on the length of the flight, and the length of the delay - which in this case is the full 24 hours as that is how long you were delayed.

There are some exceptions for compensation that fit under the banner of "extraordinary circumstances", but these have to be things that are truly extraordinary, and completely outside of the control of the airline themselves.  Something like the inbound flight being delayed would almost certainly NOT be considered extraordinary - but as you haven't stated the reason for the initial delay it's not possible to comment on whether you would be covered or not.

Comment: All i know regarding reason for a delay is that plane arrived to SVO late; and that this day specifically a lot of other LOT flights to and from Warsaw was delayed for some reason. Regarding 'Compensation', i was under impression that it is only applicable for canceled flights, not rescheduled?

Comment: @Jagd: the black-and-white language of the regulation only mentions compensation for cancellations,  yes. But the ECJ has decided that it *nevertheless* applies to delays too.

Comment: Note that it's the nationality of the *operating* carrier that matters for EC261 eligibility, not that of the carrier that sold the ticket. So the OP may be put off luck if the flight from Moscow was a codeshare.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aircraft was owned by LOT, so should not be a case.

Comment: I'm not sure that the statement "all EU carriers are covered by EU261 regardless of where the flight is to/from" is correct as a blanket statement.  The [interpretive guidelines](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52016XC0615%2801%29) issued by the EU are pretty clear (Section 2.1.1) that it only applies to flights originating in the EU, and flights into the EU by EU carriers.  An EU carrier operating between two non-EU airports wouldn't be covered. ...

Comment: For example, British Airways is (checks watch) still an EU carrier, and operates SIN–SYD flights that would presumably not be covered under EC261.

Answer (score 3):

It matter the delay at YYZ, so around 24 hours. This is what you paid, and what it is in your tickets. Rebooking give you boarding access to the new flight, but it doesn't change the contractual ticket.

Note: often they will find an other flights (possibly connecting to an other airport): it is often cheaper compared to let you wait 24 hours, and so paying you hotel and meals. For compensation of delays, you will have to fight (usual excuse: unforeseen problem, outside their control), but for hotel and meals they should pay you at airport, so this is a real expenses for them.